# What's a nice title for a persuasive essay arguing that affirmative action is not helpful?

Tags: essay, titles

What is a good clever title for a persuasive essay against affirmative action? In general, how do you come up with clever titles?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Requests for single-line rephrasings are not on topic for us, but they are okay at English. I'll ask the mods to migrate.

Comment: We can't tell you [what to write](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/397/should-we-be-answering-questions-about-what-to-write-about), that's off-topic here. You can also have a look at our [tour] to see why brainstorming questions like this tend not to work well here.

Comment: Your title should summarize your essay: What is it about? and: What did you find? or: What do you argue? Your title should not be clever or metaphorical or grabbing the reader's attention, but concise and to the point. The title is like an abstract in less words. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_%28summary%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Affirmative action as a detriment/hindrance" "Affirmative Action: Doing more harm than good."

Go over your essay and see if there are any good "tag lines" think of how a movie comes up with the trailer. The title should reflect the overall point of the essay, or be a short version "elevator pitch" of your first paragraph, the one thats usually all, "over the course of this essay i intend to change your opinion about ZYX, to XYZ, as i feel XYZ to be better, and this is why" kind of stuff.

Maybe do a cover letter rather than just a title. teachers usually like it when you go the extra mile.

"Persuasion of truth: The facts they don't want you to know about Affirmative Action."
"Affirmative Actions harmful and unforeseen consequences"

you see, it should just reflect the main view of your essay. try to boil down your essay into the lowest common denominator.

"Affirmative Action, Racist Institution?"